# How do I restore a now empty icon in the favorites launcher after update to 20.04

Tags: launcher, icons, 20.04

Update from 19.10 to 20.04 seems to have gone off without a hitch except I have a blank space in my favorites bar that was previously occupied by an icon for gnucash.  If I hit the super key and search for gnucash the proper icon is displayed and it runs fine.  The blank space in the launcher highlights a square the size of an icon and if I click it gnucash starts fine.  It is as if there is an icon there, there just aren't any graphics.  It is installed via the repositories and was updated without any problem that I can see.

/user/share/applications/gnucash.desktop looks like the following except for the purposes of this forum I had to edit out all the translation names because they included disallowed special characters.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
MimeType=application/x-gnucash;
Version=0.9.4
Name[ca]=GnuCash
Comment=Manage your finances, accounts, and investments
Exec=gnucash %f
# Icon file name, do not translate unless you also provide a localized icon file. Alternatively use the English "gnucash-icon" as msgstr
Icon[fa]=gnucash-icon
Icon[ja]=gnucash-icon
Icon[uk]=gnucash-icon
Icon[zh_CN]=gnucash-icon
Icon[de]=gnucash-icon
Icon[es]=icono-gnucash
Icon[he]=gnucash-icon
Icon[hr]=gnucash-icon
Icon=gnucash-icon
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Categories=Office;Finance;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=GnuCash
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=General
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.8
X-GNOME-DocPath=gnucash/gnucash.xml
X-GNOME-FullName=GnuCash Finance Management
```

Comment: can you post the contents of `.desktop` file for that app? probably u will get answer ur self while adding the details to Q.

Comment: I'm going to leave this open for now because I don't think my solution is a universal or proper answer.  I changed the icon manually in the desktop file but that shouldn't be necessary after an update in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Tweaks, select extensions, select settings, then change the icon to a size that it will display at, on my system it seems to be 32 or 48. It does it immediately. My dock is at the bottom of the screen, and i can see the icon wink in and out as i slide the slider along.

Comment: Ok so this solved it but I have to wonder. Maybe this isn't a bug but it certainly seems less than optimal.  I notice that it also works in the Settings>Appearance default app. Also that the sizes that work match PNG files in the /usr/share/icons/hicolor folder.  I don't understand why gnucash acts this way and programs don't.